# What does 'Inherited' mean in StyleData?

Tags: notebooks, formatting

I'm having a trouble with notebook styling.

Please, consider the following, self explicative, screenshoot.

[image]

I thought that this code

```
StyleDefinitions->Notebook[{
   Cell[
    StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
   Cell[
    StyleData["ItemParagraph"], CellMargins -> {{81, 100}, {4, 1}}, 
    FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSlant -> 
    "Plain", FontVariations -> {
     "StrikeThrough" -> False, "Underline" -> False}], 
   Cell[
    StyleData["SubitemParagraph"], CellMargins -> {{105, Inherited}, {4, 1}}, 
    FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSlant -> 
    "Plain", FontVariations -> {
     "StrikeThrough" -> False, "Underline" -> False}, FontColor -> 
    RGBColor[1., 0., 0.5019607843137255]], 
   Cell[
    StyleData["Title"], CellMargins -> {{27, 300}, {10, 30}}, FontFamily -> 
    "Arial", FontSize -> 24, FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSlant -> "Plain", 
    FontVariations -> {"StrikeThrough" -> False, "Underline" -> False}], 
   Cell[
    StyleData["Subtitle"], CellMargins -> {{27, Inherited}, {10, 30}}, 
    FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 24, FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSlant -> 
    "Plain", FontVariations -> {
     "StrikeThrough" -> False, "Underline" -> False}, FontColor -> 
    RGBColor[1., 0., 0.5019607843137255]]}, Visible -> False, FrontEndVersion -> 
  "8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (February 23, 2011)", StyleDefinitions -> 
  "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
```

would produce `SubitemParagraph` aligned at rigth respect to `ItemParagraph` and, similarly, for `Subtile` and `Title`, but, obviously, I was wrong. So I wonder: what does 'Inherited' exactly mean in StyleData ?

Comment: In each case the style is inheriting the value defined in the default stylesheet or core stylesheet

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Can I implement the above feature in a straight way or I must necessarily resort to CurrentValue ?

Comment: @m_goldberg the linked question actually does not discuss the `Inherited` symbol. Thus, I do not believe it can be a duplicate.

Comment: I agree. I'm meditating on a change to make my question clearer. Anyway, Mike's comment is in itself an answer. The difference between "default stylesheet" and "core stylesheet" should be explained.